# Perform doubleClick functionality on function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having html table and inside that tr and td. Now all my Td are having different classes. i want to perform operation like whenever i call one function, a particular td having particular class automatically perform double click functionality and one value which i pass will store in that td.I am having editable td where user will provide a value.

```js
function setAutometicallyValue() {
  $(".columndata").bind("dblclick", function() {
    $('.columndata').val("4");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td class="columndata">Message</td>
    <td class="1">Test</td>
    <td class="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="button" onclick="setAutometicallyValue()">
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. There are no buttons in your HTML, `td` elements don't have a value to set, and you have a typo in the selector.

Comment: `$(',columndata').val("4");` should be `$('.columndata').val("4");` or use `$(this).val("4");`.

Comment: @PratikJoshi i have posted answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```js
function setAutometicallyValue() {  
    $('.columndata').text("4");  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td class="columndata">Message</td>
    <td class="1">Test</td>
    <td class="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="button" ondblclick="setAutometicallyValue()">
```